# How to get a middle value in regex statement?

Tags: python, regex

Given a string, I want to get out the id by finding the prefix (which is constant) and the suffix, which may or may not exist. Here are the possible cases that would need to be handled:

```
item: item_id { item_data }
```

```
item: item_id { 
    item_data
}
```

```
item: item_id
{ 
    item_data
}
```

In each situation, I'm trying to get out 'item_id'. Here are the approaches I'm currently attempting:

1. Use `item:\s*(.*)` as the regex statement, then manually delete all '{' and '}'. This fails for the first example I wrote above because it keeps item_data in the search statement
2. Use `item:\s*(.*){` as the regex statement, then manually delete the brackets as well. This fails for the third example where there isn't an opening bracket signifying the end of the statement.

What should I do here? I can't seem to create a regex statement that can handle all three cases without breaking something else. I also tried using  `item:\s*(.*){??` to make the statement non-greedy, but this doesn't work at all.

Comment: Should explore be in the example data?

Comment: my bad - I wrote the wrong thing. Edited to better fit my examples

Comment: `item:\s*(.*)\s*{`? btw, since you've tagged this as python, maybe include the python code you're using to executre this regex and make your examples python strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`item:\s*(\w+)`

Explanation: `\w` will match only `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9` and `_` (underscore). Otherwise you can use `[^{\s]` (everything except spaces and curly brace) instead of `\w`. Like this: `item:\s*([^{\s]+)`

Also consider changing `\w` to `\d` or maybe `[<your possible tokens in id>]`

You can check the result here: https://regex101.com/r/mgAYf0/1